# Is there evidence to suggest that the Klingon Ship of the Dead is a Hur'q vessel from the invasion?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, star-trek-discovery

In Star Trek Discovery [S1:E2](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_at_the_Binary_Stars_(episode)) *Battle At The Binary Stars* we see The [Ship Of The Dead](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sarcophagus).

We know that the [Hur'q](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hur%27q) invaded the [Klingon Homeworld](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Qo%27noS) in roughly Earth's history 14th Century - and from this the Klingons got Warp Technology.

We know that the bodies on the ship are thousands of years old, suggesting the ship is thousands of years old. (Whereas the Klingons have had Warp Drive technology for 1000 years by the time of TNG).

This would also explain how the Klingons got the Cloaking Device (discovered on the ship) and then spread it around and improved it.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that the Klingon Ship of the Dead is a Hur'q vessel from the invasion?**

Comment: It's a cool sounding theory though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## No.

*S.T. : Discovery* is the only series where the Sarcophagus ship is featured, and on this series the Hur'q are never mentioned or referenced in any way.

**So, for what we know right now, there is not any evidence that the Sarcophagus is of Hur'q origin.**

Also, the assumption that the Klingons got the warp technology from the Hur'q is not supported by any kind of canonical reference.

Comment: There is also prior evidence to indicate Klingons had interstellar travel (ie, warp drive) prior to the 14th century as well. In the episode of TNG when the clone of Kahless showed up ("Rightful Heir"), the monastery on the planet of Borath had been there for more than 1500 years, putting its founding in the 9th century, or not long after the death of Kahless.